# Linear Mixed Models: Testing the significance of a random factor using ranova() on the ouput of lmer() in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, glmm

We have a dataset with a response (dependent) numeric variable called "CTIR", a fixed (non-random) independent/explanatory numeric variable called "Temperature" and a random factor called "Tank". We are using a Linear Mixed Model to explain the effects of Temperature on CTIR and accounting for the effects of the random factor “Tank“.

We want to test the significance of the random factor "Tank". Is the following approach correct? If not, what is the correct approach to test whether the random effect significantly contributes to a better model fit?

Using the `ranova()` function from the `lmerTest` package:

Input (R):

```r
model <- lmer(CTIR ~ Temperature + (1 | Tank), data = ctirtemp)
ranova_result <- ranova(model)
print(ranova_result)


#Checking the normality of the residuals:

residuals = residuals(model)
shapiro.test(residuals)
```

Output:

```
ANOVA-like table for random-effects: Single term deletions

Model:
CTIR ~ Temperature + (1 | Tank)
           npar  logLik    AIC     LRT Df Pr(>Chisq)
none         4 -28.916 65.833                      
(1 | Tank)    3 -29.103 64.206 0.37305  1     0.5413
```

Our interpretation: Based on the high p-value, the random effect is not significant and we can use the model to explain the variability in CTIR caused by Temperature?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "we can use the model to explain the variability in CTIR caused by Temperature". If you have repeated measures and the random intercept isn't extremely close to zero or causing convergence issues, I would include it in the model. You should not decide to remove predictor variables or random effects based on significance tests.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, your specific question

> Based on the high p-value, the random effect is not significant and we can use the model to explain the variability in CTIR caused by Temperature?

is a little unclear.

- Your model seems fine, as far as we can tell from the information you've given.
- Using the likelihood ratio test to evaluate the statistical significance of random effects is reasonable, but sub-optimal for reasons discussed [in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/481884/2126); the p-values you get will be conservative. For a linear mixed model such as yours, you could use the [RLRsim package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RLRsim) to get more reliable p-values (for *generalized* mixed models you would need something like the [PBmodcomp package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=PBmodcomp)) [also see the [relevant section of the GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#testing-significance-of-random-effects)]
- as suggested in the comments, you shouldn't necessarily drop random effects terms just because they're non-significant (opinions differ here — I agree with @Roland that you *generally* shouldn't, although Matuschek et al. argue for stepwise backward selection with a relaxed LRT $\alpha = 0.2$; whether you should drop random effect terms or not also depends on the goal of your analysis)

---

Matuschek, Hannes, Reinhold Kliegl, Shravan Vasishth, Harald Baayen, and Douglas Bates. “Balancing Type I Error and Power in Linear Mixed Models.” Journal of Memory and Language 94 (June 1, 2017): 305–15. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jml.2017.01.001.